# How to iterate a 4GB CSV file on virtual private server that has only 1 GB memory available to PHP?

Tags: php, csv, iteration

So my case is like this:

I do have a CSV 4GB comma separated value file and my virtual private server has only 1 GB of memory dedicated to PHP.

My question is this:

Is there any way to allocate memory for only one CSV row at a time instead of reading the entire 4GB file into memory?

Example code:

```
<?php
function getRows($file){
    $handle = fopen($file, 'rb');
    if($handle === false){
        throw new Exception();
    }
    while(feof($handle)===false){
        $line_of_txt=fgetcsv($handle);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return $line_of_txt;
}
foreach(getRows('DWBankStatmentApril.csv') as $row){
    print_r($row);
}
?>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Loading time; 4GB data on a VPS with only 1 GB can tell where is the issue; obviously poor use of memory. I wanna see if there is any way to iterate large data sets witj only a tiny amount of system memory.

Comment: I asked which errors did you get, any specific one?

Comment: How are you trying to read the file currently? Can you provide us with any code to look through?

Comment: Sure, just `fopen` it and `fgetcsv` to read it line by line rather than reading the whole file into memory. [Like this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#refsect1-function.fgetcsv-examples).

Comment: @PedroLobito Fatal error: Out of memory...

Comment: If you're already doing it that way, you'll need to include your code here for anyone to be able to tell why it's still using too much memory.

Comment: Are you trying to load the entire file into PHP Memory? If so, don't.... process it a record at a time

Comment: I am trying to read a line at the time but for some reason I am not able to do that as the file is HUGE and system memory is low. Wondering if there is any way to process the data using a small amount of memory.

Comment: @Don't Panic I am doing it that way but not working.

Comment: Are you actually printing the entire file? Where is your output going? Is this a CLI script or are you sending that output to the browser?

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes even in this CLI is giving me: danielwellingtonserver# php
Out of memory

Comment: Your example code won't do much good, while you're only ever returning the last line of the file.... consider using a generator, and yielding that line in the getRows while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it right now.

```
 <?php
function getRows($file){
    $handle = fopen($file, 'rb');
    if($handle === false){
        throw new Exception();
    }
    while(feof($handle)===false){
        yield=fgetcsv($handle);
    }
    fclose($handle);

}
foreach(getRows('DWBankStatmentApril.csv') as $row){
    print_r($row);
}
?>
```

The issue was solved by using a generator instead, they are mainly used for forward-only interating large data sets with a tiny amount of system memory.